# Simple_Form and Bootstrap : input as date how to specify different width for month and year?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I have a date field in a simple_form like this :

```
<%= f.input :dob, as: :date, start_year: Date.today.year - 12,
                      end_year: Date.today.year - 110, discard_day: true,
                      order: [:month, :year],
                      label: "Date of birth"  %>
```

It works fine but each select (month and year) has the same width.

I would like to specify a different width for the year part, any idea on how to achieve this ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this in your stylesheet since Rails and simple_form will tag the input forms with IDs.

Example. Say you have a Person model and you are trying to grab the dob.

**Rendered snippet form partial (_form.html.erb)**

```
<select class="date required" id="person_dob_3i" name="person[dob(3)]">
```

**Person stylesheet person.css.scss**

```
#person_dob_3i {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. The post is a bit old now, and I have solved it by myself and post my solution as answer to another post here (I put it for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860467/styling-the-date-fields-of-a-rails-date-select/15921437#15921437).