# Styling the date fields of a Rails date_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activesupport, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails' forms, date `select` drop-downs are easy:

```
<%= f.label :my_date %>
<%= f.date_select :my_date %>
```

Then I get 3 `select` drop-downs for the year, month and day. Is there an easy way to add HTML between these `select` elements without using JavaScript? I want to be able to style and label them nicer.

Comment: the best idea is to use datepicker.

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to a text field and add a JQuery datepicker or similar.

Theres a good guide here, http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars

Answer (score 1):

You can easily style them with CSS as each part of date_select is postfixed with '_1i', '_2i' etc . For a date_select with id 'my_date' you can use

```
#my_date_1i  // the year
#my_date_2i  // the month
#my_date_3i  // the day
```

Hope this helps

Cheers